# How do I configure multiple monitors (dual screens) in xorg without basic mosaic in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

Normally when configuring multiple monitors in Ubuntu I would configure my nvidia cards in xorg to use basic mosaic. But since upgrading my GPUs basic mosaic is no longer listed as a option in the version of `nvidia-settings` the Binary driver ships with and configuring it in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or via the version of nvidia-settings in the repos prevents gnome from starting and I have to run `nvidia-xconfig` again to get back into gnome. I tried configuring xinerama but when I reboot after that I get the  `A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up` error when ever I boot up. Seems Nvidia doesn't want us to have Multiple Monitors any more.